# How to draw over a imagesc image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, line, image-scaling

I have a function:

```
A = [5,16,18,4,9;
    9,10,14,3,18;
    2,7,9,11,21;
    3,7,2,19,22;
    4,9,10,13,8]

figure
colormap(gray)
imagesc(ones(15,15))
axis off
for t = 1:15
    for k = 1:15
        text(t, k, sprintf('%c', A(t,k) + 96))
    end
end
```

And I want to draw a line between one position and another say from (1,2) to (4,5) how can I achieve this, I think I can use either the plot or line functions but am not sure how to use them.

Comment: Note that your indices do not match the size of the matrix A, I adapted them accordingly in my code below.

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't get anything wrong:

```
A = [5,16,18,4,9;
    9,10,14,3,18;
    2,7,9,11,21;
    3,7,2,19,22;
    4,9,10,13,8]

figure
colormap(gray)
imagesc(ones(5,5))
axis off
for t = 1:5
    for k = 1:5
        text(t, k, sprintf('%c', A(t,k) + 96))
    end
end
hold on;
line([1 2], [4 5]);
```

Result:

[image: Output]